# Page break issue in PDF in froala editor

Tags: javascript, froala

Any one have any knowledge of froala editor. I ma using it to edit webpage and generate it as a PDF. The HTML template contains a dynamic data, and when I generate a PDF the page break happen between the content, which looks quite bad. Does any one knows how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom button and modify the html2pdf plugin inside the callback.

```
FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('customDownload', {
    NAME: 'plus',
    SVG_KEY: 'add'
  });
  FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('customDownload', {
    title: 'Custom Download PDF',
    focus: true,
    undo: true,
    refreshAfterCallback: true,
    callback: function() {
      var element = this.el;
      var opt = {
        margin: 1,
        filename: 'myfile.pdf',
        image: {
          type: 'jpeg',
          quality: 0.98
        },
        html2canvas: {
          scale: 2
        },
        jsPDF: {
          unit: 'in',
          format: 'A4',
          orientation: 'portrait'
        },
        pagebreak: {
          mode: 'avoid-all',
          before: '#page2el'
        }
      };
      html2pdf(element, opt);
    }
  });
  new FroalaEditor('#selector', {
    toolbarButtons: ['customDownload']
  });
```